# Reveal like animation Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to create an animation like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu3wc.jpg

I did try the `CircularReveal` animation, but this does not quite look like a `CircularReveal`. This is also the animation Google Play Store uses when going from a list of apps to its individual page. I have looked it up a lot but in vain. Please help by pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement very  slimier to  FABRevealLayout
 Hope this library helps you

https://github.com/truizlop/FABRevealLayout

https://github.com/sephiroth74/ViewRevealAnimator

Thank you

Comment: Let me know your result